# How can I quickly query SQLite given a list of rowids?

Tags: ios, sql, sqlite

How can I quickly query for records that match a list of rowids? I have a query in my iOS app that looks like this:

```
SELECT rowid, category_id
FROM items
WHERE rowid in (2, 4, 89, 4243, 44, 555, ...)
```

The list of rowids can be somewhat long - a few hundred items would be a typical example.

The odd thing is that this query takes several seconds to run - as much as 12 seconds in some cases. It's slow whether I run it in the SQLite shell or whether I run it in my app.

However, if I replace this query with just:

```
SELECT rowid, category_id
FROM items
```

so I retrieve EVERY item in the table (in my test case, around 1000 rows) and just have my app ignore the rowids it doesn't need, the query executes in just a few hundred milliseconds. It also responds quickly at the SQLite shell.

What's happening here? `rowid` is a primary key, so this should be a fast, indexed lookup. Is there a faster way to run queries like this? I would've thought it was parsing the query string that makes the difference, but profiling shows almost all time is spent in `sqlite3_step`.

Comment: Hmmm, the `WHERE rowid in(.....)` should be pretty good performance as opposed to other solutions. Is there anything outside that query that could possibly slow down your query response?

Comment: `WHERE...IN` does not work quite well with large lists, because _internally_ it will be treated as a large _OR_ list which cannot be optimized that well. But you could try this approach: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/28/why-large-in-clauses-are-problematic/

Comment: @Martin I don't think so, since I see the issue in the SQLite shell

Comment: @AndreasOetjen So basically, use a temp table?

Comment: @Bill Yes, something to JOIN with. Depending on your use case - maybe your id list does not change that frequently - a persisted id table could also be a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

SQL query with out where clause is always faster than query with where class. You mention RowID is primary key (so, its cluster index created by default) in your table.

Please try to replace 'where...In' with 'where...between' or where...rowId>X and RowId

Other solution is move comparable row ids list to temp table / view and perform inner join to get the results faster.